# How can I store java method outcomes in karate feature file variable?

Tags: karate

How can I store java method outcomes in karate feature file variable?

I can able to call java method but How can I store java method outcomes in karate feature file variable?

Eg: Feature file:

```
def result = call reusableMethod
print result
```

Error

```
O/p: 16:18:34.694 [main] INFO com.intuit.karate - [print] date is : undefined
```

Common.feature

```
def reusableMethod = """ function() { var JavaDemo = Java.type('utilities.reusable'); jd = new JavaDemo(); return jd.createDate(); } """
```

Java class file:

```
public class reusable { 
  public void createDate(){ 
   int a =1;
   int b =1;
   int c= a+b; 
 } 
}
```

Note: My question is how can i store above c output in karate feature file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java method which you are calling should return some value to store.

But your `createDate` method returns `void`, it should be int / respective data type and `return` that object.

```
public class reusable { 
  public int createDate(){
    int a =1; 
    int b =1; 
    int c= a+b;
  return c;
 } 
}
```